# Overriding methods and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, overriding

Iam having a bit of a problem with this question I have been asked to complete the following class.

```
public class UpDownTrack extends OpenTrack
{
    //allowedDirection attribute required
    private TrainDirection allowedDir;

    //Add a constructor to set the initial state to down
    public UpDownTrack()
    {
        allowedDir = DOWN;
    }

    //Override the useTrack method so that only one train at a time 
    //can use the track
    public synchronized void useTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {

       try
       {
         enterTrack(trainDir,  id);
         traverse();
         exitTrack(trainDir,id);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         System.out.println("Error" + e);  
       }


    } 

    // Override the enterTrack method so,a train going in the opposite
    // direction is only allowed to enter the track
    //Then display that a train has entered the track
    public synchronized void enterTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {
       if(allowedDir != trainDir)
       {
         try
         { 
           System.out.println("Train " + id + " entered track, going " + trainDir);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
       }


    }

    //Override the exitTrack method so that the direction is changed
    //before the track is exited
    //Then display that a train has exited the track
    public synchronized void exitTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {     
        System.out.println("   Train " + id + " left track, going " + trainDir); 
        trainDir = (trainDir == DOWN)? DOWN : UP;  
        notifyAll();
    }

 }
```

Methods to overide from the OpenTrack class

```
    public void useTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {  
        enterTrack(trainDir,  id);

        traverse();

        exitTrack(trainDir,id);
    }

    //This method doesn't currently check if it is safe to traverse the track.
    //It just reports that a train has entered the track.
    void enterTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {
        System.out.println("Train " + id + " entered track, going " + trainDir);
    }

    //This method currently just reports that a train has left the track
    void exitTrack(TrainDirection trainDir, int id)
    {
        System.out.println("   Train " + id + " left track, going " + trainDir);
    }   


}
```

Problem is im getting the wrong output, i should get

```
Train 1 enters track going up
Train 1 leaves track
Train 3 enters track going down
Train 3 leaves track
Train 2 enters track going up
```

and so on, but im getting now sequence and jumbled up output

Answer (score 0):

`TrainDirection` is a class of yours and when you concatenate an instance of it to a string (such as here: `System.out.println("   Train " + id + " left track, going " + trainDir);`), it calls the `toString` method of the class. But the default `toString()`, which is inherited from `Object` returns the object hashcode and not the actual direction. So you need to override the `public String toString()` method in the class `TrainDirection` so it will return a useful information to you (such as the direction of the train...)